# Why I can't pass ip to rsync script?

Tags: bash, rsync

I am writing script were rsync should be called and ask for password.
However I cannot pass IP as argument. I think I am missing something simple. Any ideas? Even trivial script like this just outputs nothing, just stucks:

`rsync -avzh -P  $1 $3@$2:/opt/stuff/`

When I put IP it worked:

`rsync -avzh -P  $1 $3@192.168.0.100:/opt/stuff/`

Tried escaping colon, didn't helped, echo'ed everything and it just showed similar line. I think it is something related to interactivity.

Comment: Are you sure about the value of `$2` at that point? Print it out with `printf '[%s]\n' "$2" | cat -v` to check that it contains the IP address only.

Comment: In my case I got `[192.168.1.100]` no hidden symbols, nothing

Comment: Run your script with the `-x` flag: `sh -x myscript dirname address username`. This will show you how `sh` interprets your script.

Comment: `+ rsync -avzh -P ../file.txt user@192.168.1.100:/opt/stuff` - perfect, but still same results.

Comment: Wait after some time I got: 
`"ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.100 port 22: Connection timed out
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]
"`

Comment: Connection times out but it does not prompt me for anything.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't [use ssh keys](http://paulkeck.com/ssh/)? That would remove the need for interactive password prompts to work through your shell script.

Comment: I will try it. Really very little need for password, I just need to generate new ssh keys to target machines.